# Adding json array response in range slider angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, slider

I got a json response like this. It is dynamic and I want to add the details in range slider. The slider max value must dynamically increases when there will be new element in array.

```
"time": [
        "2018-05-24T06:30:00",
        "2018-05-24T07:00:00",
        "2018-05-24T07:30:00"
]
```

I have never worked on slider before . Any suggestion how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [angularjs-slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) library (which has `ui-bootstrap` as dependency). It offers lot customization in sliders & very handy with angularjs.
For your case after every new value added to array you can reload the slider by 1st deleting it & then loading it again. Or you can use their `rzSliderForceRender` custom event for that. Using this

Your HTML will look like:

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="slider_dates.value"
          rz-slider-options="slider_dates.options"></rzslider>
```

And in controller slider config code as:

```
$scope.dates = ["2018-05-24T06:30:00",
  "2018-05-24T07:00:00"];
var datesObjests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
  datesObjests.push(new Date($scope.dates[i]));
}
$scope.slider_dates = {
  value: datesObjests[0],
  options: {
    stepsArray: datesObjests,
    translate: function(date) {
      if (date !== null) return date.toLocaleString();
      return '';
    },
  },
};
```

Working [**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QwpI9SzMVNnrbRnS09Gr?p=preview) for your requirement.

Comment: My` $scope.dates` is array[ ] value response which I am calling in `$scope.load_timeline` by `$scope.load_timeline = response.data.TimeL;` So When I am implementing my scope like this in slider `$scope.dates = $scope.load_timeline;` shows `NaN` value . nothing happens. Where I am going wrong in this. array must not be declared as you have shown in example. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks , it is working now . I included the slider function in the GET function itself.